# What does the int value returned from compareTo function in Kotlin really mean?

Tags: string, kotlin

In the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/compare-to.html) of `compareTo` function, I read:

> Returns zero if this object is equal to the specified other object, a
> negative number if it's **less than** other, or a positive number if it's
> **greater than** other.

What does this `less than` or `greater than` mean in the context of strings? Is -for example- `Hello World` less than a single character `a`?

```
val epicString = "Hello World"
println(epicString.compareTo("a")) //-25
```

Why `-25` and not `-10` or `-1` (for example)?

Other examples:

```
val epicString = "Hello World"
println(epicString.compareTo("HelloWorld")) //-55
```

Is `Hello World` less than `HelloWorld`? Why?
Why it returns `-55` and not `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, etc?

```
val epicString = "Hello World"
println(epicString.compareTo("Hello  World")) //55
```

Is `Hello World` greater than `Hello  World`? Why?
Why it returns `55` and not `1`, `2`, `3`, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're asking about the implementation of `compareTo` method for `java.lang.String`. Here is a source code for java 11:

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
        byte v1[] = value;
        byte v2[] = anotherString.value;
        if (coder() == anotherString.coder()) {
            return isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.compareTo(v1, v2)
                              : StringUTF16.compareTo(v1, v2);
        }
        return isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.compareToUTF16(v1, v2)
                          : StringUTF16.compareToLatin1(v1, v2);
     }
```

So we have a delegation to either `StringLatin1` or `StringUTF16` here, so we should look further:

Fortunately `StringLatin1` and `StringUTF16` have similar implementation when it comes to `compare` functionality:

Here is an implementation for `StringLatin1` for example:

```
public static int compareTo(byte[] value, byte[] other) {
        int len1 = value.length;
        int len2 = other.length;
        return compareTo(value, other, len1, len2);
    }

    public static int compareTo(byte[] value, byte[] other, int len1, int len2) {
        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
        for (int k = 0; k < lim; k++) {
            if (value[k] != other[k]) {
                return getChar(value, k) - getChar(other, k);
            }
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    }
```

As you see, it iterated over the characters of the shorter string and in case the charaters in the same index of two strings are different it returns the difference between them. If during the iterations it doesn't find any different (one string is prefix of another) it resorts to the comparison between the length of two strings.

In your case, there is a difference in the first iteration already...

So its the same as `"H".compareTo("a") --> -25".

The code of "H" is 72

The code of "a" is 97

So, 72 - 97 = -25

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: The exact value doesn't have any meaning; only its sign does.

As the specification for [`compareTo()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/compare-to.html) says, it returns a -ve number if the receiver is smaller than the other object, a +ve number if the receiver is larger, or `0` if the two are considered equal (for the purposes of this ordering).

**The specification doesn't distinguish between different -ve numbers, nor between different +ve numbers — and so neither should you.**  Some classes always return `-1`, `0`, and `1`, while others return different numbers, but that's just an implementation detail — and implementations vary.

Let's look at a very simple hypothetical example:

```
class Length(val metres: Int) : Comparable<Length> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Length)
        = metres - other.metres
}
```

This class has a single numerical property, so we can use that property to compare them.  One common way to do the comparison is simply to subtract the two lengths: that gives a number which is positive if the receiver is larger, negative if it's smaller, and zero of they're the same length — which is just what we need.

In this case, the value of `compareTo()` would happen to be the signed difference between the two lengths.

However, that method has a subtle bug: the subtraction could overflow, and give the wrong results if the difference is bigger than `Int.MAX_VALUE`.  (Obviously, to hit that you'd need to be working with astronomical distances, both positive and negative — but that's not implausible.  Rocket scientists write programs too!)

To fix it, you might change it to something like:

```
class Length(val metres: Int) : Comparable<Length> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Length) = when {
        metres > other.metres -> 1
        metres < other.metres -> -1
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

That fixes the bug; it works for all possible lengths.

But notice that the actual return value has changed in most cases: now it only ever returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`, and no longer gives an indication of the actual difference in lengths.

If this was your class, then it would be safe to make this change *because* it still matches the specification.  Anyone who just looked at the sign of the result would see no change (apart from the bug fix).  Anyone using the exact value would find that their programs were now broken — but that's their own fault, because they shouldn't have been relying on that, because it was undocumented behaviour.

Exactly the same applies to the `String` class and *its* implementation.  While it might be interesting to poke around inside it and look at how it's written, the code you write should never rely on that sort of detail.  (It could change in a future version.  Or someone could apply your code to another object which didn't behave the same way.  Or you might want to expand your project to be cross-platform, and discover the hard way that the JavaScript implementation didn't behave exactly the same as the Java one.)

In the long run, life is much simpler if you don't assume anything more than the specification promises!